# vue lazy routing not showing new chunk js file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

In my `routes/index.json,` I have the following.

```
const Signin = () => import('@/components/Authenticate/Signin')

{ path: '/signin', component: Signin, beforeEnter: beforeRouteLoggedIn },
```

The bad thing is, when I go to the main page at http://localhost:8080, I see .js and .css file getting loaded. Now I click signIn page, and what I expect to see is in network tab, new .js file should be generated, right? But after clicking signin, even though it should be lazy loaded, no new js file gets loaded in network tab.

Comment: Is there only problem with time of loading or the login page does not work?

Comment: all the routes work. time is good, but i wanted to figure this out why no new js file gets generated after visiting lazy loaded component route.

Comment: Seems like your code works fine and you deal with prefetch. Try to read this article https://medium.com/@mrodal/how-to-make-lazy-loading-actually-work-in-vue-cli-3-7f3f88cfb102

Comment: do you know where I can find vue.config.js? I only have vue-loader.config.js, webpack.base.conf.js,webpack.dev.conf.js, webpack.prod.conf.js, build.js

Comment: Just create it in the root directory to add some webpack settings.